# Why must the components $g_{0i}$ of an isotropic, homogeneous spacetime metric vanish?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, symmetry

In Daniel Baumann's book on Cosmology, it says that the metric of an isotropic, homogeneous spacetime must have the form $$\mathrm{d}s^2=-\mathrm{d}t^2+a^2(t)\gamma_\mathrm{ij}(x)\mathrm{d}x^\mathrm{i}\mathrm{d}x^\mathrm{j}.$$

In a footnote he says that components like $g_\mathrm{0i}$ must vanish, otherwise it would introduce a preferred direction, which would break isotropy.

I wonder what exactly he means by this. How would a direction be preferred if none of those components vanished?

Comment: The book "Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to Relativity" from Barrett O'Neil contains a discussion of why it must be like this in the section on Robertson-Walker spacetimes.

Comment: $\omega=\sum_{k=1}^3g_{k0} dx^k$ has a direction in the three space at given $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rotate the axes of the spatial co-ordinates system (the $i$ co-ordinate axes in the $g_{0i}$ vector) then the values of any non-zero $i$ co-ordinate elements in $g_{0i}$ will change. But an isotropic metric must be invariant under spatial rotations.